# Julia: How to convert numeric string with power symbol "^" into floating point number

Tags: julia

I'm having trouble converting an array of numeric strings into an array of corresponding floating point numbers. A (hypothetical) string array is:

```
arr = ["8264.", "7.1050^-7", "9970.", "2.1090^-6", "5.2378^-7"]
```

I would like to convert it into:

```
arr = [8264., 1.0940859076672388e-6, 9970., 0.011364243260505457, 9.246079446497013e-6]
```

As a novice of Julia, I have no clue on how to make power operator "^" in the string format to do the correct job in the conversion. I highly appreciate your suggestions!

Answer (score 5):

This function would parse both forms, with without the exponent.

```
function foo(s)
    a=parse.(Float64,split(s,'^'))
    length(a)>1 && return a[1]^a[2]
    a[1]
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat ugly, but gets the job done:

```
eval.(Meta.parse.(arr))
```

**UPDATE:**

Let me elaborate a bit what this does and why it's maybe not good style.

`Meta.parse` converts a `String` into a Julia `Expr`ession. The dot indicates that we want to broadcast `Meta.parse` to every string in `arr`, that is apply it to every element. Afterwards, we use `eval` - again broadcasted - to evalute the expressions.

This produces the correct result as it literally takes every string as a Julia "command" and hence knows that `^` indicates a power. However, besides being slow, this is potentially insecure as one could inject arbitrary Julia code.

**UPDATE:**

A safer and faster way to obtain the desired result is to define a short function that does the conversion:

```
julia> function mystr2float(s)
           !occursin('^', s) && return parse(Float64, s)
           x = parse.(Float64, split(s, '^'))
           return x[1]^x[2]
       end
mystr2float (generic function with 1 method)

julia> mystr2float.(arr)
5-element Array{Float64,1}:
 8264.0
    1.0940859076672388e-6
 9970.0
    0.011364243260505457
    9.246079446497013e-6

julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime eval.(Meta.parse.($arr));
  651.000 μs (173 allocations: 9.27 KiB)

julia> @btime mystr2float.($arr);
  5.567 μs (18 allocations: 1.02 KiB)
```

**UPDATE:**

Performance comparison with @dberge's suggestion below:

```
julia> @btime mystr2float.($arr);
  5.516 μs (18 allocations: 1.02 KiB)

julia> @btime foo.($arr);
  5.767 μs (24 allocations: 1.47 KiB)
```